# Why this ChildEventListener is not reading data from firebase node?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have a query to firebase node with ChildEventListener shown in image link 
[image]

now when I run this code

```
mMessageRef.child(ScrollAppUtils.firebaseId).child(child.key).orderByKey().limitToLast(1).addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {

    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError?) {}

    override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {}

    override fun onChildChanged(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {}

    override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot?, p1: String?) {

        Logger.d("inside onChild Added")
        if (p0!!.hasChildren())
        {

        var lastMessage = p0.getValue(MessagesTwo::class.java)
        var dialog = DefaultDialog(child.key, user.metaData.profileImage, user.metaData.name, arrayListUser, lastMessage, 2)
        if (!listDialog.contains(dialog)) {

            listDialog.add(dialog)
            Logger.d(listDialog.size)
            dialogListAdapter.setItems(listDialog)
            dialogListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else {
            Logger.d("inside updateItemByID : ")
            Logger.json(Gson().toJson(dialog))
            dialogListAdapter.updateItemById(dialog)
            dialogListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
        }


    }

    override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot?) {}
    })
```

**this listener simply doesn't work when a node not found**,  which I believe should work as ValueEventListener is working very well but I have some other problem with that listener so I am compelled to use this listener. Please suggest me what is I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onChildAdded` method is called for each child not of the location (or query). If there are no matching child nodes, `onChildAdded` will not be called.

If you want to detect the situation where there are no child nodes, you'll (also) need to use a `ValueEventListener`.

Also see:

- [Firebase onChildAdded not called when there is no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631148/firebase-onchildadded-not-called-when-there-is-no-data/40632920#40632920) (which this question is really a duplicate of)
- [Can I determine if query does NOT find any children with values within a specified range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900082/can-i-determine-if-query-does-not-find-any-children-with-values-within-a-specifi/39900316#39900316)
- [What happens if a firebase url doesnot exist and we try to add a listener to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460779/what-happens-if-a-firebase-url-doesnot-exist-and-we-try-to-add-a-listener-to-it/34463972#34463972)
- [Firebase queryOrderedbyChild doesn't return a Null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598870/firebase-queryorderedbychild-doesnt-return-a-null-value/44599584#44599584)

Comment: thanks for replying. I am now using ValueEventListener

Answer (score -1):

This is a java code but you can get the idea

```
 ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hasChildren ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getDesigns();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
};
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
```